# How to correctly display a table in normal pdf size? (have to enlarge it to show the correct table)

Tags: tables

Below is the code to generate a table

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\definecolor{c1}{RGB}{229,223,236}
\definecolor{c2}{RGB}{234,241,221}
\definecolor{c3}{RGB}{198,217,241}
\definecolor{c4}{RGB}{242,219,219}
\definecolor{c5}{RGB}{229,184,183}
\definecolor{c6}{RGB}{217,149,148}
\definecolor{c7}{RGB}{148,54,52}
\definecolor{c8}{RGB}{184,204,228}
\definecolor{c9}{RGB}{214,227,188}
\definecolor{c10}{RGB}{229,184,183}
\definecolor{c11}{RGB}{246,246,246}
\definecolor{c12}{RGB}{234,241,221}
\definecolor{c13}{RGB}{219,229,241}
\definecolor{c14}{RGB}{238,236,225}
\usepackage{makecell,multirow}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{colortbl,hhline}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
There is a theory which states that...

\begin{table}[h!t]
\caption{Database classification based on data model}
\tabcolsep=4pt\begin{tabular}{|l|p{160pt}|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor{c8}\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Category}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Data model}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Examples}} \\
\hline\rowcolor{c9}
If the optional  & If the optional argument is & AAA, BBB \\\hline\rowcolor{c9}
If the optional argument & If the optional argument is used & CCC, DDD \\\hline\rowcolor{c9}
If the optional & If the optional & EEE, FFF \\\hline\rowcolor{c9}
Graph Database & If the optional argument is used Usedd  & GGG, HHH \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab301}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The table is shown below, but it is not displayed correctly in normal size, there is no column line between the first and second column
[image]

To display it correctly, I have to enlarge the pdf file to 110% or 300%
[image]

How can I display the table without enlarge the pdf file?

Comment: if you have some input and it is making the wrong output, then probably the input is wrong, but if you do not show any input it will be hard for anyone to correct it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the output is not wrong, just I have to enlarge it to show the table correctly

Comment: that is wrong. But as posted images rescale , and you don't show any context it is impossible to tell _anything_ about your input or output or what size it is. putting \large before a tabular will make it larger putting \small before it will make it smaller. Really how do you expect anyone to answer this question?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle now i have revised my question, please see it, or remove our discussion here, since the question changed?

Comment: @postit: This is a problem with the viewer (most likely you're using Adobe). Try it in anything else (Foxit, Sumatra, ...), and you may see the problem disappear.

Comment: It is a well known problem (even documented in the colortbl package that you are using) that some viewers fail to show lines at some resolutions. It is basically a feature of the pdf reader. It is best to ignore it, or you could try increasing \arrayrulewidth slightly. (Note I wrote that code and I would never have guessed your original question was about that issue)

Comment: @Werner great answer! Sumatra is fine, no problem. How ever I think adobe probably is the most popular tool, I cannot exclude my future reader to use Adobe. So for readers with adobe, nothing can do?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks, can you show an example by using \arrayrulewidth for this problem?

Comment: @postit: This would be very similar to writing a web-page that is solely geared towards IE. Many people use IE, but not all, and other browsers may/may not have a problem. And since the problem is not with LaTeX, but with another user application, you can only suggest to your viewers in a note. Even then, your document may open at different zoom levels on different computers based on their resolution; so some people will never see the problem. My point is, don't worry about it.

Comment: Not really you just need to try \setlength\arrayrulewidth{.5pt} or some other value but it depends on the resolution of your screen, the default scale size of the viewer the exact version of acrobat, .....

Answer (score 2):

Your code is good, the problem is the used pdf viewer.

The problem with the different pdf viewers is that all of them differs in their functionality. It is well known.

That means for example,

- some of them can show lines in a special screen resolution, some not,
- some can show text if a mouse hovers over a text, most of them not,
- ...

My experience is, that the best way to check if the viewer has a problem or not is to print the file.  Lines not shown on the screen are shown on the print if the line is in the pdf.

The second way is to open the pdf file with several other pdf viewers, for example Adobe Acrobat Reader, SumatraPDF, etc.  and check, if the line is shown there.  If only one of them shows the line the pdf file is okay.

Answer (score 0):

As already explained in the other answer, that what you're noticing is a pdf viewer issue rather than a LaTeX issue.

I'd like to encourage you to consider side-stepping the PDF viewer entirely -- simply by removing all vertical and horizontal black lines. You're already using color very effectively to group the tabular material; the black lines are thus quite redundant.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{c1}{RGB}{229,223,236}
\definecolor{c2}{RGB}{234,241,221}
\definecolor{c3}{RGB}{198,217,241}
\definecolor{c4}{RGB}{242,219,219}
\definecolor{c5}{RGB}{229,184,183}
\definecolor{c6}{RGB}{217,149,148}
\definecolor{c7}{RGB}{148,54,52}
\definecolor{c8}{RGB}{184,204,228}
\definecolor{c9}{RGB}{214,227,188}
\definecolor{c10}{RGB}{229,184,183}
\definecolor{c11}{RGB}{246,246,246}
\definecolor{c12}{RGB}{234,241,221}
\definecolor{c13}{RGB}{219,229,241}
\definecolor{c14}{RGB}{238,236,225}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage[skip=0.5\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{makecell,multirow,diagbox,hhline}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
There is a theory which states that \dots

\begin{table}[h!t]
\caption{Database classification based on data model}
\label{tab301}
\tabcolsep=4pt
\extrarowheight=1pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lYl}
\rowcolor{c8}
\textbf{Category} & \textbf{Data model} & \textbf{Examples} \\
\rowcolor{c9}
If the optional  & If the optional argument is & AAA, BBB \\
\rowcolor{c9}
If the optional argument & If the optional argument is used & CCC, DDD \\
\rowcolor{c9}
If the optional & If the optional & EEE, FFF \\
\rowcolor{c9}
Graph Database & If the optional argument is used Usedd  & GGG, HHH \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```